# How can I get my domain to do this?

Tags: url, dns, server

I was just wondering how you would do this for a domain name?

```
name.example.com
```

How would you make entering a url like above, direct to somewhere on a server?
example:
forum.example.com would take you to a forum on the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this looks like more of an Apache question than a DNS question.

For DNS, you need to add the proper IP address and subdomain to your DNS entry on your authoritative DNS server.

```
www     A    AAA.XXX.YYY.ZZZ
forum   A    AAA.XXX.YYY.ZZZ
```

These can be different servers, if you're looking to host `forum` on a different server than your `www` page.  For more information on DNS configuration files (depending on how you're doing your DNS configuration - although the syntax is reasonably universal) - see [here](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch6/mydomain.html).

I'm assuming, though, you want to host both `www` and `forum` on the same server, but serve from different file directories for each.  For Apache, you just create a virtual hosts like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName  forum.example.com
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/forum/"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName  www.example.com
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/"
</VirtualHost>
```

This allows Apache to serve out of different directories, based on the incoming server request.  For more information on name-based VirtualHosts, see [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html).